# How do I encode html leaving out the safe html

Tags: xss, html-encode

My data coming from the database might contain some html. If I use

```
string dataFromDb = "Some text<br />some more <br><ul><li>item 1</li></ul>";
HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(dateFromDb);
```

Then everything gets encoded and I see the safe Html on the screen.

However, I want to be able to execute the safe html as noted in the dataFromDb above.

I think I am trying to create white list to check against.

- How do I go about doing this?
- Is there some Regex already out there that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998274.aspx) the [AntiXSS library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) is also worth a look

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Microsoft AntiXSS library. I believe the latest version is available [here](http://wpl.codeplex.com/). Specifically, you'll want to use the [GetSafeHtmlFragment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedab/archive/2009/09/16/antixss-v3-1-new-features.aspx) method.